# Eye in object mode

Tags: mesh

Hello i imported a base mesh from blender swap and have been editing it.But im making eyes and when im in edit mode they move fine.But when i veiw them in object mode they warp all over, they look like deforming water balls as i move them to fit better in the face.Can yo please help.

Also the x topology so that when you edit one side the other moves exactly the same dose not work all that well neither.

Comment: are you using modifiers on the eye?

Comment: The screenshots of the model in Object & Edit mode and mesh properties (like Modifiers and Object data tabs' contents) illustrating the problem would be very helpful. In addition you can [include .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (or a part of it) in the question.